# Linear algebra over natural numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modules, integers

I am given a $m\times n$ matrix $M$ and a $m$-vector $y$.  I want to find a $n$-vector $x$ such that $Mx=y$ (or determine that no solution exists).  However, I have an extra constraint: all entries of $x$ are required to be non-negative integers.  All of the entries of $M,y$ are non-negative integers as well.

Is there a general technique to solve this kind of problem? Is there an efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: About your question: the problem can be, in general, tough, as you must check whether $\;y\;$ belongs to the span of the matrix's *columns* , so in general you will have to solve, or prove there is no solution, a linear system of equations, generally non-homogeneous (unless $\;y=0\;$ but then there's always the trivial solution).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a version of the [multi-dimensional knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem).

To make things precise, put $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_m)^t$ and $M=(m_{i,j})_{1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j\leq n}$.  Then your problem, formulated as a knapsack problem, would be:
$$
\textrm{maximize} \quad \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n m_{i,j}x_j \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots, m\}, \sum_{j=1}^n m_{i,j}x_j \leq y_i \ \textrm{and} \ \forall j\in\{1, \ldots n\}, x_j\geq 0. \\
$$

If there is a solution such that the quantity to maximize is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^m y_i$, then it is a solution to your problem.

Judging from [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01224914/document), it is not so easy to solve the multi-dimensional knapsack problem.  Some algorithms are described in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Algorithms), the keyword being *integer linear programming*.

Note that if you remove the constraint that the solution is given by *non-negative* integers, then your problem becomes that of solving a [system of linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations), and this can be done by finding the Smith normal form of the matrix $M$ (the precise method is described in the above link).

Comment: Interesting!  So my problem is a special case of multi-dimensional knapsack, i.e., no harder than multi-dimensional knapsack.  Could it be easier than multi-dimensional knapsack?  Or is there a reduction going the other way, too?  Thanks for sharing this connection!

Comment: @D.W. That is a good question.  I suspect they are equivalent, since integer linear programs containing inequalities are often first converted to an integer linear program containing only equalities (this is the [standard form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Canonical_and_standard_form_for_ILPs) of the program).